# How to tell when a TTTableViewController scrolls

Tags: ios, three20

I'm using Three20's TTTableViewController and I'd like to know when the user scrolls the table view. With a regular UITableViewController I can just listen in on scrollViewDidScroll:. How can I do this in a TTTableViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Just overrides two methods `didBeginDragging` and `didEndDragging` in your TTTableViewController.